# How to set color by pointer to color name?

Tags: ios, uicolor

Normal, I often setBackgound color by:
aView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

Now I keep all color name in an NSArray:

```
colorsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:
               @"blackColor",
               @"darkGrayColor",
               @"lightGrayColor",
               @"whiteColor",
               @"grayColor",
               @"redColor",
               @"greenColor",
               @"blueColor",
               @"cyanColor",
               @"yellowColor",
               @"magentaColor",
               @"orangeColor",
               @"purpleColor",
               @"brownColor",
               nil];
```

And I want to set background by a NSString pointer like that

```
NSInteger i = 0;
for (aView in viewArray) {
   NSString *colorName = [colorsArray objectAtIndex:i];
   aView.backgroundColor = color with colorName;//Can't find a method to set
   i++;
}
```

I check UIColor class and can't find  any method to set color with pointer to colorName.
Please help! Any another way? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A little bit of reflection and the medicine goes down...

```
NSInteger i = 0;
for (aView in viewArray) {
    NSString *colorName = [colorsArray objectAtIndex:i];
    aView.backgroundColor = [[UIColor class] performSelector:NSSelectorFromString(colorName)];
   i++;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
aView.backgroundColor = [UIColor performSelector:NSSelectorFromString(colorName)];
```

Comment: @AnoopVaidya My initial edit was exactly like yours (with incorrect `@selector(` bit) before I realised it was wrong and removed it.  It might be a coincidence, and if so I apologize.

Comment: And i deleted my answer now :)